# How to search for rented house in Netherland as an Indian Expat who does not know Dutch?

Tags: netherlands, rental, amsterdam

For an Indian who (does not know Dutch language) is relocating from India to Netherlands what are the easiest way to search for rented house?

Given the conditions that:

1. He need to work form Home for most of the time and need to go to ofice in Amsterdam very occasionally (may be once in a week).
2. He is relocating with spouse and 2 year old kid
3. House need is of 1 Bedroom Studio or Apartment in a budget of 1000-1500 Euros

Comment: Rents in Amsterdam are very high, and the Dutch train system is very good. You could easily travel to and from the office on the train one day a week, and live in another town or city with lower rents. Many do this, even people who must go to the office every day.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Thanks, what places do you recommend and how do I search for houses in those suggested areas?

Comment: All four of the websites noted in the Answer by einpoklum allow one to specify the city searched. I'll note as well that the entire country speaks English without difficulty. As to where: it's a small country. I know a fellow who lives in Utrecht and travels daily to attend work in Amsterdam. Ask your soon-be-employer where to look. You could also look at train routes and stations, and seek places that have good connections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, and very importantly: There are some cases of scam attempts, when people pretend to own an apartment, and rent it out supposedly to someone who's about to arrive in the Netherlands - and they ask for a sum of money in advance. It's important to look out for that. Never agree to anything before someone you trust has physically been in the apartment, at the very least.

Having said that - when I was in the same situation in 2015, I used (among other things) websites publishing apartments for rent. Examples:

- https://directwonen.nl/en
- https://kamernet.nl/
- https://www.funda.nl/en/huur/
- https://www.pararius.com/apartments/

You could also try to avail yourself of a real-estate agent, or "makelaar".

About "not knowing Dutch" - in the cities, a large majority of people speak English; and there are lots of expat apartment renters, so that part will usually be ok.

At any rate, and again from my experience 7 years ago, in Amsterdam - it was tough to find a reasonable apartment. Prepare to possibly have to stay at some hostel, or AirBnB place, or for free with one of  [BeWelcome](https://bewelcome.org/) host (recommended! It's a great community of hospitality exchange) - for the days after you arrive; and maybe even switch temporary places of residence.

Comment: Scamming people like that over apartment rentals isn't confined to the Netherlands.    I've had people try and do that to me in the US

Comment: @PeterM: Fair enough, but in many (most?) countries - this is unheard of.